# Rescue and this external API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the following code to query maxmind for geolocation of a user's IP address. I want to make sure I am prepared for any errors/timeouts from maxmind's servers. Should I implement some type of `rescue`?  If so, what is recommended?

```
uri = URI("https://geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/#{request.remote_ip}?pretty")

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', 
  :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|

  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
  request.basic_auth 'USER_ID', 'KEY'

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object

  if response.kind_of? Net::HTTPSuccess
    location_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

To rescue all exceptions:

```
begin
    #your code
rescue Timeout::Error, Errno::EINVAL, Errno::ECONNRESET, EOFError,
    Net::HTTPBadResponse, Net::HTTPHeaderSyntaxError, Net::ProtocolError => e
    # do something with exception
end
```

You can also rescue single errors putting different rescues (use comma to rescue more than one at once):

```
begin
    # your code
rescue Timeout::Error => e

rescue Errno::EINVAL => e

...

end
```

Comment: When you say #your code do you actually mean all of the code I used above would go between begin and rescue? Sorry I am new at this.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Every line of code that could raise an exception. You can leave the uri = Uri(...) line out if you prefer.